# HTML Select items count in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html-select

I've an HTML `select` control in my ASP.NET page and I made it as `runat = "server"` and now I tried to add some list items to it dynamically. Something like below code

```
var list = document.getElementById('<%=list1.ClientID%>');
var newListItem = document.createElement('OPTION');
newListItem.text = "Emp1";
newListItem.value = "e101";
list.add(newListItem);
```

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlemp" runat="server" 
    Style="display: none;" 
    CssClass="modalPopup" 
    width="700px" Height="350px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
               <select id="list1" multiple="true"  name="list1" runat="server">
               </select>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

and now when I try to access this from my code like `list1.Items.Count` it is showing `0`.

Anything wrong in this?

Comment: When you are calling your Javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution to this problem **either** add items dynamically through server side code **or** 
dont bring server side into the picture and handle everything via javascript.

Items added via javascript will not be persisted by asp.net. further more you may recieve a "Invalid Callback or PostBack Argument" Exception for the same because it will not understand from where these listitems(options) have been added in the Select.

Answer (score 1):

When you modify the html in a client side script, the viewstate (which keeps track of all the controls) doesn't update . That results in that when you make a postback the new items isn't "there" .

Sometimes there's a __doPostBack() javascript which forces a postback, but I'm not sure it'll work .

Comment: when my page is getting postback it is resetting to zero. Is there any other way to get it resolved?

Comment: __doPostBack is just a javascript method that is used to submit the form mainly on controls with an AutoPostBack property. so in this case it will not work.

Comment: Then i don't know anything that can fix it. Sry